# How to escape a space returned from nested bash command

Tags: bash, escaping

The title is slightly confusing since the problem itself is confusing.

Prerequisites:

I use this script `script.sh` as a playground for the parameters passed:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

Problem:

I expect this call

```
./script.sh $( echo "foo \"bar baz\"" )
```

to behave exactly as

```
./script.sh foo "bar baz"
```

Correspondingly, I expect to get

```
foo
bar baz
```

as the output result but it returns

```
foo
"bar
baz"
```

Obviously, I need to escape something. I suspect it's a space, but I'm not sure.

The question: how the nested `echo` call should look like so that the outer call received 2 arguments

PS: this is a simplification of a more complicated script, but the main problem of the original call is kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. Whatever `$(somecommand)` will be treated as data, not interpreted as shell syntax, so any quotes and escapes in it will simply be treated as regular characters. This is what you're seeing -- the double-quotes that `echo` prints are being treated as parts of the arguments to `./script.sh`, rather than as delimiters *around* arguments.

Another way to think of this is in terms of the process that the shell goes through as it parses a command line. Here's a highly simplified summary:

1. Parse the command line, including quotes and escapes. Note that the quotes and escapes get removed in this process.
2. Expand things like variables (`$var`) and command substitutions (`$( )` and backquoted commands).
3. Perform word splitting and wildcard expansion on the results of those expansions (unless they were in double-quotes from step 1).

Note that by the time the results of any variable expansion or command substitution is part of the command line, quote and escape parsing has already been done; the shell simply doesn't apply that processing to the results of those expansions.

Now, depending on what you're actually trying to do, there might be another way to accomplish it. For example, there are ways to use `read` or `xargs` to split a string while respecting quotes/escapes within it. There's also `eval`, but avoid that if at all possible -- it has a well-deserved reputation as a bug magnet.

Comment: Yep, I think `echo "foo \"bar baz\"" | xargs ./script.sh` is the best from all alternatives. Thanks.